# Is this weighted average smaller than the corresponding arithmetic average?

Tags: statistics, inequality, average, means

Is it true that the following weighted-average is smaller than the respective arithmetic average
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left(\frac{b_{n}}{\sum_{m=1}^{N}b_{m}}\right)\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\overset{?}{\le}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}
$$
for all $a_n \in [0,1]$, $b_n \in [1, D]$, and $D \ge 2$?

Without the $a_n$'s it would simply be true by Jensen's inequality and the convexity of $x\mapsto 1/x$ (for positive $x$'s), but with the $a_n$ in the mix it is not so clear and it seems one cannot directly apply [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality) either.

**Edit:** it is easy to see that one can upper bound the numerator in the parenthesis by $D$ and lower bound the corresponding denominator by $N$, obtaining the desired upper bound with an extra $D$ term. I was wondering however if one can do better in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the claim for $N=2$, suppose $b_2 > b_1$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\,
&
\left(\frac{b_1}{b_1+b_2}\right)\left(\frac{a_1}{b_1}\right)
+
\left(\frac{b_2}{b_1+b_2}\right)\left(\frac{a_2}{b_2}\right)
\le
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}\right)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
\frac{a_1+a_2}{b_1+b_2}\le\frac{a_1b_2+a_2b_1}{2b_1b_2}\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
(b_1+b_2)(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)-(2b_1b_2)(a_1+a_2)\ge 0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&
(b_2-b_1)(a_1b_2-a_2b_1)\ge 0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a_1b_2-a_2b_1\ge 0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&a_1b_2\ge a_2b_1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\frac{a_1}{a_2}\ge \frac{b_1}{b_2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
which need not be true.